# Azure Services tutorial: HttpResponseMessage' does not contain a definition for 'StatusDescription'

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services

I am following one of the Azure Mobile Services 'getting started' tutorials here:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/validate-modify-and-augment-data-dotnet/

In Step 4, the tutorial adds an exception handler, and the catch code has a compile error for me.

```
catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException e)
{
    MessageDialog errormsg = new MessageDialog(e.Response.Content, 
        string.Format("{0} (HTTP {1})",                     
        e.Response.StatusDescription,      // ERROR *
        e.Response.StatusCode));
    var ignoreAsyncOpResult = errormsg.ShowAsync();
```

- 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' does not contain a definition for 'StatusDescription'

Looks like the class has changed since the demo was built.
Any ideas what would be appropriate here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the documentation, thanks for pointing it out. The property name should be `ReasonPhrase`, and correct code should be:

```c#
catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException e)
{
    MessageDialog errormsg = new MessageDialog(e.Response.Content, 
        string.Format("{0} (HTTP {1})",                     
        e.Response.ReasonPhrase,
        (int)e.Response.StatusCode));
    var ignoreAsyncOpResult = errormsg.ShowAsync();
}
```

I'll notify the team to have it fixed.

Comment: Thank you @carlosfigueira, but there is another layer to this issue. Although the change you recommend does compile and report a 'Bad Request' error as expected, it does not pass through the explanation string as created by the server script:  (sorry, can't format this response comment, here is the 'insert' script I created on the server per the tutorial)  `code`  function insert(item, user, request) { if  item.text.length > 10) { request.respond(statusCodes.BAD_REQUEST, 'Text length must be under 10');
    } else {
        request.execute();
    }

}